# Spring AOP Poincut expression

Tags: spring-aop

I want to create a pointcut expression to intercept all method calls to all classes within the package com.xmy.package and its sub packages. My xml, code looks like below

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="allCalls" expression="within(com.xmy.package..*)" />
    <aop:aspect ref="loggingService">
        <aop:around method="logMethodFlow" pointcut-ref="allCalls" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class......
>   ..
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
>           at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)

But when I use a pointcut expression for a particular class(as  below) it works fine.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="classCalls" expression="execution(* com.xmy.package.MyClass.*(..))" />
    <aop:aspect ref="loggingService">
        <aop:around method="logMethodFlow" pointcut-ref="classCalls" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Please let me know how to log all method calls to a specific packages and its sub packages.

Answer (score 0):

Point cut for all method calls in specific packages and their subpackages. For example
`com.xmy.package1.subpackages` ...
`com.xmy.package2.subpackages` ...

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pkg1AllCalls" expression="execution (* com.xmy.package1+*())" />
    <aop:pointcut id="pkg2AllCalls" expression="execution (* com.xmy.package2+*())" />
    <aop:aspect ref="loggingService">
        <aop:around method="logMethodFlow" pointcut-ref="pkg1AllCalls" />
        <aop:around method="someOtherMethod" pointcut-ref="pkg2AllCalls" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

i.e. Define 2 different pointcuts that makes expressions both concise and maintainable. **Note** that `someOtherMethod()` was something I added new to use two different pointcuts.

There is a limitation with XML based style If you had to merge two pointcuts as shown above ref: 6.4.2 Section of Spring Docs 3.0

However this can be easily achieved when used as @AspectJ

```
@Pointcut(execution(* get*()))
  public void propertyAccess() {}

  @Pointcut(execution(org.xyz.Account+ *(..))
  public void operationReturningAnAccount() {}

  @Pointcut(propertyAccess() && operationReturningAnAccount())
  public void accountPropertyAccess() {}
```